# Omnet++ Question: Using Standard Container Classes for Fields of abstract L3Address SlectedNodes[]; // will use std::vector?

Tags: omnet++

I want to use Standard Container Classes for Fields of abstract L3Address SlectedNodes[]; // will use std::vector? I have made the following message declaration:

enter code here

```
packet PacketData {
@customize(true);
abstract L3Address SlectedNodes[]; // will use std::vector<L3Address >
}
```

In the generated C++ code i write the following C++ file :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "PacketData_m.h"
class PacketDataPacket : public PacketData_Base
{
protected:
std::vector<L3Address> SlectedNodes;// SlectedNodes= SlectedNodes
// helper method
void unsupported() {throw cRuntimeError("unsupported method called");}
public:
// SlectedNodes methods
virtual L3Address getSlectedNodes(unsigned int k) {return SlectedNodes[k];}
virtual void setSlectedNodes(unsigned int k, const L3Address& SlectedNodes) 
{SlectedNodes[k]=L3Address& SlectedNodes;}
virtual void addSlectedNodes(const L3Address& SlectedNodes) 
{SlectedNodes.push_back(L3Address& SlectedNodes);}
virtual void setSlectedNodesArraySize(unsigned int size) 
{SlectedNodes.resize(size);}
virtualL3Address getSlectedNodesArraySize() const {return 
SlectedNodes.size();}
};
Register_Class(PacketData);
```

Some additional boilerplate code

```
 PacketData_Base::PacketData(const char *name=nullptr, int kind=0) 
:PacketData_Base(name,kind) {
}
PacketData_Base:: PacketData(constPacketData& other) 
:PacketData_Base(other.getName()) {
operator=(other);
}
PacketData& operator=(const PacketData& other) {
if (&other==this) return *this;
PacketData_Base::operator=(other);
 SlectedNodes = other.SlectedNodes;
}
virtualPacketData *dup() {
 return newPacketData(*this);
}
```

Is this use of standard container classes (STL) as fields, but of
`std::vector< L3Address> IntVector;` is true? is there any wrong?